# How to properly leverage power of index in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am using MySql 8.0.

Here are index information about a table I am working with.

`show index from my_table;` outputs

```
      Table       Non_unique      Key_name    seq_in_index   Column_name     collation    Cardinality   Index_type
     my_table       0           PRIMARY            1          NO                A         612173902      BTREE
     my_table       0           PRIMARY            2          STATS_DTTM        A         612173902      BTREE
     my_table       0           my_table_UK_01     1          STATS_DTTM        A         3665711        BTREE
     my_table       0           my_table_UK_01     2          PAR_NO            A         9418060        BTREE
     my_table       0           my_table_UK_01     3          ADVRTS_TP_CODE    A         9418060        BTREE
     my_table       0           my_table_UK_01     5          USSER_ID          A         612173902      BTREE
     my_table       1           my_table_IDX_01    1          Gamer_ID          A         1264822        BTREE
     my_table       1           my_table_IDX_01    2          STATS_DTTM        A         1919040        BTREE
     my_table       1           my_table_IDX_02    2          STATS_DTTM        A         1769288        BTREE
```

Since my table has too many rows I want to

1. get range of data
2. perform aggregation + calculations
3. repeat 1,2 for multiple range of data
4. combine aggregated datas.

STATS_DTTM columns contains date value in such form 20210104, in integer format.

I try to query one day at a time using

```
SELECT *
  FROM FRME_COMBI_DAY_STATS
 WHERE STATS_DTTM = 20201227;
```

However this doesn't output any rows.

My guess is because STATS_DTTM primary key can be used only after NO primary key has been used since it is 2nd in seq_in_index.

But STATS_DTTM has another key(foreign) how can I leverage that to get rows with specific date? If it is not possible what would be most efficient way to get each day's data? Other than using No column.

Column datatypes are as follows:

Columns             Type
NO                 bigint(20)
STATS_DTTM          int(11)
PAR_NO              int(11)
ADVRTS_TP_CODE      varchar(2)
USSER_ID            varchar(30)
GAMER_ID            varchar(30)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; the index list seems to be incomplete.  Please provide more sample `SELECTs`.

Comment: How many rows for `STATS_DTTM = 20201227` -- It looks like the estimate is 3.6M rows.  Does that sound feasible?  If so, what will the client do with that much stuff?

Comment: We need to see the datatypes; `20201227` works in some contexts, but maybe not for the datatype you are using.

Comment: @RickJames STATS_DTTM = 20201227 contain about 4.6M rows. Also I've updated data types for each columns.

Comment: Well, 4.6M rows takes a long time to shovel from the database to the client.  That's not an indexing question, that's a networking issue.  "doesn't output any rows" -- it may _still_ be working on the query.  You mention 4 types of queries; let's switch to discussing _specific_ cases of them.